# LIst in Python is empty but not empty - Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract path of the files changed in gitee. I can see there is only one file present in the files changed section but when I try to get it, 2 empty blocks comes along with the file. I checked everything but not sure why this is happening. Following is my code. The URL I am trying to extract fixed files from gitee is this - https://gitee.com/openharmony/arkui_ace_engine/pulls/27841/files

```
files_changed = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@class = "header file-header clearfix  file-header-sticky"]//a')
files = []
count = count + 1
filecount = 1
for z in files_changed:

    temp =list((z.text).split(' '))
    if not temp:
        print("A Blank File")
        filecount = filecount + 1
                                    
    else:
        print("This is the temp value:", temp)
        temp.insert(0,filecount)
        files.append(temp)
        print("List of files changed:", files)
        filecount = filecount + 1
                                    
    
temp_issue['files_changed'] = files
```

The output I get from the above code is this:

```
This is the temp value: ['']
List of files changed: [[1, '']]
This is the temp value: ['']
List of files changed: [[1, ''], [2, '']]
This is the temp value: ['test/unittest/core/pattern/overlay/overlay_manager_test_ng.cpp']
List of files changed: [[1, ''], [2, ''], [3, 'test/unittest/core/pattern/overlay/overlay_manager_test_ng.cpp']]
```

The output I expect to achieve is this:

```
This is the temp value: ['test/unittest/core/pattern/overlay/overlay_manager_test_ng.cpp']
List of files changed: [[1, 'test/unittest/core/pattern/overlay/overlay_manager_test_ng.cpp']]
```

I even tried if(temp!= '') then.. But this didn't work either. Clearly, the list is not empty but it is displaying as empty. How to solve this please?

Comment: `['']` isn't an empty list; it's a list with one element, namely the empty *string*. If `z.text` is supposed to be a series of white-space delimited file names, you probably want to remove any leading or trailing whitespace first: `z.text.strip().split(' ')`.

Comment: (If you were using `split` in an attempt to access a filename sandwiched *between* whitespace, then just use `strip` *instead* of `split`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the locator you are using to find the paths. In your case, you are finding 3 elements, only 1 of which is visible and what you are looking for. That's why you are getting the first two blank list items.

Use the CSS selector `div.diff-file > div > a` instead. It is finding only the desired elements.

A quick way to test this is to use the dev tools console. You can use `$$(locator)` to test CSS selectors and `$x(locator)` to test XPaths, e.g. `$$("div.diff-file > div > a")`. If you run this in the console, you will see only 1 returned element. If you run yours, you will see 3 elements returned. You can expand the returned element section and click into each returned element to see it in the DOM to determine if it's a correct element, etc. and then refine your locator to only return what you want.

Comment: It worked thanks! However, I am not sure how to use the dev tools console. Please edit your answer a bit more elaborative.

Comment: Press F12 to open the dev tools, the console should show. For more info, here are [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools) for Chrome.

Comment: What you are asking is a different question. SO rules require only one issue/question per question so that answers, etc. can be tracked properly. I would suggest you do some googling on the double quotes issue because while I don't know the answer off hand, I'd be really surprised if someone hadn't already asked that question on SO before. If you can't find an already existing question, please create a new question describing just the double quotes issue with your minimal code to repro the issue, what you expect, and what you are getting and why it's not what you want, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I just figured it out that by converting int to string and inserting it added the double quotes :)